# boost split with a single character or just one string

Tags: c++, string, boost

I wish to split a string on a single character or a string. I would like to use `boost::split` since boost string is our standard for basic string handling (I don't wish to mix several techniques).

In the single character case I could do `split(vec,str,is_any_of(':'))` but I'd like to know if there is a way to specify just a single character. It may improve performance, but more importantly I think the code would be clearer with just a single character, since **is_any_of** conveys a different meaning that what I want.

For matching against a string I don't know what syntax to use. I don't wish to to construct a regex; some simple syntax like `split(vec,str,match_str("::")` would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code, let me assume `using namespace boost` for brevity.
As for splitting on a character, if only `algorithm/string` is allowed,
`is_from_range` might serve the purpose:

```
split(vec,str, is_from_range(':',':'));
```

Alternatively, if `lambda` is allowed:

```
split(vec,str, lambda::_1 == ':');
```

or if preparing a dedicated predicate is allowed:

```
struct match_char {
  char c;
  match_char(char c) : c(c) {}
  bool operator()(char x) const { return x == c; }
};

split(vec,str, match_char(':'));
```

As for matching against a string, as *David Rodri'guez* mentioned,
there seems not to be the way with `split`.
If `iter_split` is allowed, probably the following code will meet the purpose:

```
iter_split(vec,str, first_finder("::"));
```

Comment: C++11 answer: `[](char c){ return c==':'}` i.e. native lambda.

Comment: Minor quibble in MSalters excellent comment: a missing semicolon: `[](char c){ return c==':';}`

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for the same answer but I couldn't find one. Finally I managed to produce one on my own.

You can use `std::equal_to` to form the predicate you need. Here's an example:

```
boost::split(container, str, std::bind1st(std::equal_to<char>(), ','));
```

This is exactly how I do it when I need to split a string using a single character.

Comment: This doesn't work for `string_view`. It seems that boost pass iterators into the constructor of `string_view`.

Answer (score 1):

On the simple token, I would just leave `is_any_of` as it is quite easy to understand what `is_any_of( single_option )` means. If you really feel like changing it, the third element is a functor, so you could pass an `equals` functor to the `split` function.

That approach will not really work with multiple tokens, as the iteration is meant to be characater by character. I don't know the library enough to offer prebuilt alternatives, but you can implement the functionality on top of [`split_iterator`s](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html)