# C++ Boost: Split function is_any_of()

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use the `split()` function provided in  `boost/algorithm/string.hpp` in the following function :

```
vector<std::string> splitString(string input, string pivot) { //Pivot: e.g., "##"
    vector<string> splitInput;  //Vector where the string is split and stored
    split(splitInput,input,is_any_of(pivot),token_compress_on);       //Split the string
    return splitInput;
}
```

The following call :

```
string hello = "Hieafds##addgaeg##adf#h";
vector<string> split = splitString(hello,"##"); //Split the string based on occurrences of "##"
```

splits the string into `"Hieafds" "addgaeg" "adf"` & `"h"`. However I don't want the string to be split by a single `#`. I *think* that the problem is with `is_any_of()`.

How should the function be modified so that the string is split only by occurrences of `"##"` ?

Comment: Try using split_regex: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/#boost-split-regex

Comment: also, you may use iter_split(vec,str, first_finder("##")); (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5710242/1284631)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, you have to use **is_any_of()**

```
std::string input = "some##text";
std::vector<std::string> output;
split( output, input, is_any_of( "##" ) );
```

**update**

But, if you want to split on exactly two sharp, maybe you have to use a regular expression:

```
 split_regex( output, input, regex( "##" ) );
```

take a look at the [documentation example](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/).

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry. I made an error while posting the code. Corrected it now as soon as I saw your answer. I meant that if I use `is_any_of()` it checks for any of the characters in the `pivot` and splits accordingly. But I want to split it only if the pivot matches exactly.

Comment: This answer should not be downvoted because it answered an original, slightly wrong version of the question (that was later edited)